# How to commit a git repo into a git repo (not submodule)

Tags: git, nested, backup

When I try to add and commit a git repository into another git repository, git helpfully makes it into a submodule. What if I *want* to track and commit changes to that nested repository in the outer repo? I.e. I want the outer repository to track all the files in the nested repo's working tree as well as its .git directory.

The use case here is that I want to maintain a git repository of my whole "projects" directory (many of which use git or another VCS) for versioned backups, as well as statistics collection. Going to a particular commit in the outer repo should show me the complete state of all projects at that time, including e.g. commits that may later have been rebased into oblivion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible.

After researching this further I found the answer is unfortunately that it is not possible. Git is hardcoded to ignore nested git repositories and cannot be told to index them.

The most common git-like suggestion for the backup use case is [bup](https://github.com/bup/bup), which seems fine for that use case alone, but can't seem to do all that git can stats-wise.